# Free Record / Replay Web Testing Tool

Tags: asp.net, testing, web, web-testing

I have an ASP.NET application which is configured to run on my local IIS.

Anyone knows any Free Record/Replay Web Testing Tool so that I can test the pages with e.g. 10 concurrent users?

(I don't have access to Visual Studio Test/Ultimate edition to use its Web Testing tools.)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may checkout the [soapUI/loadUI](http://www.eviware.com/blog/?p=62) suite.

Comment: thanks; LoadUI seems to be a very good load testing tool but from what I have checked you can't record the user activity on the page and replay it later.

Comment: @William, yes you can. The recording is done with SoapUI. Once you have a recorded test you could pass it to LoadUI for stress testing. Please read carefully the page I have linked to in my answer. It contains a tutorial about how to achieve that: http://www.eviware.com/blog/?p=62

Comment: Woow, didn't read it carefully; thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

check Selenium tool http://seleniumhq.org/

and seleniumgrid http://seleniumgrid.thoughtworks.com/

> Selenium Grid allows you to run Selenium tests in parallel, cutting
>   down the time required for running acceptance tests to a fraction of
>   the total time it currently takes.

- [Automate web application UI testing with Selenium](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84484/light-up-your-development-with-selenium-tests/)